# How to forward all the 404 pages to the front page?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

I have a simple question...I had an old store and people bookmarked specific product pages in their browsers as well as Google search points to some specific pages. I have now installed a new version of Magento (1.9.1) and some of these URLs will not longer work (they will show the standard 404 not found Magento page).

What would be the best way to forward all these hits to the front page?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Allysin :-*

Answer (score 1):

Login to the admin, go to System>Configuration>Web and change the drop-down value for CMS No Route Page in the Default Pages section. You should be able to select your CMS Home Page.

[Here](http://www.magestore.com/magento-seo/how-to-custom-the-magento-404-page-in-frontend) is a reference with images

If manual setting doesnt help,you can try [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15489/404-redirect-to-home-page-banner-slider-not-working).

Comment: Don't make your home page be your default no-route page. Magento will serve out status 404 for whatever page becomes default no-route when displayed for that purpose, your home page will show content with 200, and then when somebody accesses a nonexistent page, will again show content with 404. Not sure how Google will handle your front page being both 200 AND 404 in their determination of indexability. If you want to retain Google's validity in indexing, old website pages should be given 301 permanent redirect to the relevant new pages on your Magento website via URL Rewrite Management.